# Cannot find class in same package

Tags: java

I am trying to compile Board.java, which is in the same package (and directory) as Hexagon.java, but I get this error:

```
Board.java:12: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Hexagon
location: class oadams_atroche.Board
    private Hexagon[][] tiles;
```

The first few lines of Board.java:

```
package oadams_atroche;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.io.PrintStream;

import p323.hex.*;

public class Board implements Piece{
>---//Fields
>---private int n;
>---private Hexagon[][] tiles;
```

The first few lines of Hexagon.java:

```
package oadams_atroche;

import p323.hex.*;

public class Hexagon implements Piece{
```

I just cannot see what I am doing wrong. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I guess you made a little copy/paste error, as you wrote twice Board, but zero Hexagon here ...

Comment: can you post first few lines of hexagon.java

Comment: Does Hexagon.java compile cleanly?

Comment: Yeah, Hexagon.java compiles fine.

Comment: Are both classes on the compilation path together?

Comment: Can you post Piece.java?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I'm quite sure you're compiling from within the wrong directory. **You should compile from the** source root-directory, and not from within the oadams_atroches directory.

Have a look at this bash-session:

```
aioobe@r60:~/tmp/hex/oadams_atroche$ ls
Board.java  Hexagon.java
aioobe@r60:~/tmp/hex/oadams_atroche$ javac Board.java 
Board.java:12: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Hexagon
location: class oadams_atroche.Board
    private Hexagon[][] tiles;
            ^
1 error
```

While if I go up one directory...

```
aioobe@r60:~/tmp/hex/oadams_atroche$ cd ..
```

... and compile:

```
aioobe@r60:~/tmp/hex$ javac oadams_atroche/Board.java 
aioobe@r60:~/tmp/hex$
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me:

```
cd SRC_DIRECTORY
javac  -cp . PACKAGE/CLASS.java
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure about different platforms, but using Netbeans on Windows, it's often easiest to just create a project.

If you're trying to compile from command line:

javac -cp . *.java