# Why does it require import although files are in the same package?

Tags: java, eclipse

As far as I know, if files are in the same package it should import the other files by definition. But I have a case where the tester class requires explicit import from another file in the same package o/w it gives red line. Can you think of anything that might cause this?
Thanks

Comment: *"Can you think of anything that might cause this?"*  Code.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  Also copy/paste the error reported.

Comment: I don't think it requires that.

Comment: Normally test classes have the same name with just the test added before somewhere.. But without your package declaration or the error messages it's not possible to do anything but guess.

Comment: does it actually not run or eclipse just gives you a red line?  The main project might simply not be visible from the test project.

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749200/cannot-find-class-in-same-package

Comment: @R.J  Great, enter an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package within another package won't be imported automatically. You should write a separate `import` statement for inner package.

Lets say

`package b` exists within `package a`

then

```
import a.*;
```

will import all class within `a` but the classes within `b` won't be imported by this statement.

To import classes within `b`, write another statement:

```
import a.b.*;
```