# Cannot access class in default package from another class/file in the same package

Tags: java

I have two classes in separate files. Both the classes are under default package. When I try to access a class from main() function of other class, I get a class not found compilation error.

I have tried compiling the code from outside of the folder as suggested in this answer - [Cannot find class in same package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749200/cannot-find-class-in-same-package)
But it didn't work. So maybe something else is wrong here.

First class:

```
import some.package1;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class First<Item> implements Iterable<Item> {

    private int a = 0;
    private Item[] b;
        ...
        ...
        ...
}
```

Second class:

```
import some.package2;
public class Second {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       First<String> obj = new First<String>();
   }
}
```

Compilation error :

```
>>javac -cp ,;somepackage.jar Second.java
Second.java:4: error: cannot find symbol
           First<String> obj = new First<String>();
           ^
  symbol:   class First
  location: class Second
1 error
```

EDIT: 
Not the duplicate of the mentioned question. I am not trying to import class from a default package. Both the classes are in default package. So I don't have to import.

Comment: Your code should work, can you share your file structure ?

Comment: Here, packages are different, don't you need to import

Comment: I think you entered a comma instead of a dot..can you confirm it again: javac -cp .;somepackage.jar Second.java

Comment: @akshayapandey You are right. It works after correcting the typo. If you answer this, I can mark it correct. Thanks!

Comment: @Lesiak Not a duplicate. Edited to explain.

Comment: @aniztar thanks..i am happy to have helped you out..

Comment: Indeed, I removed my comment